# can't type in Input field after changing onChangeText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, formik

I have a custom **FieldInput** icon where I use Native Base's input component. I use it for validation with Formik. When I use it like this:

```
 onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
```

everything seems to work fine but I get an error on onChangeText that

```
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Input>): Input', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((text: string) => void) | undefined'.
```

When I change it to

```
 onChangeText={()=>handleChange(fieldType)}
```

the error is gone but then my input field stops working. I can no longer type into it. What am I doing wrong? My component looks like this:

```
type FieldInputProps = React.PropsWithRef<{
  handleChange: (e: string) => void;
  value: string;
  fieldType: string;
  placeholderText?: string;
  style?: object;
  rounded?: boolean;
}>;


export const FieldInput = React.forwardRef<Input, FieldInputProps>(({
  handleChange,
  fieldType,
  placeholderText,
  value,
  style,
  rounded,
}, ref) => {

  return (
    <Item rounded={rounded} style={[styles.inputItem, style]}>
      <Input 
        ref={ref}
        autoFocus={true}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
        value={value}
       />
      </Item>
  );
});
```

**Codesandbox:** https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/carefree-cereal

Comment: your fieldType not defined inside the arrow function. Try sending the event.

Comment: you mean something like this? ```(fieldType)=>handleChange(fieldType)```, I tried that too but it didn't work either. Could you maybe try on the codesandbox? @kingneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onChangeText` is a function that takes 1 argument `value`

`onChangeText` is `(value: string) => void`

So you just need to use `onChangeTextCallback` like in the example below

```
 // ✅ Right way to do it!✅ 

const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')

<TextInput value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />

// or onChangeText={(newValue: string) => setValue(newValue)}
```

---

```
// Your code
// ❌ Wrong way to do it! ❌

onChangeText={()=>handleChange(fieldType)}
// You forget about value here
// onChangeText={(value: string)=> handleChange(fieldType)}
// You need to provide value to your changing value callback
```

Let me know if it helps you!‍♂️

UPD:

Check the link -> https://snack.expo.io/bLEsPJXPS

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help me. I'm already doing what you suggested. Even if I use ```onChangeTextCallback```, the overloading error still exists. Did you have a look at my code or the sandbox?

Comment: Yeap I did and fixed all stuff ->  https://snack.expo.io/bLEsPJXPS

Comment: Please let me know if it helps you

Comment: So the main problem was that I was doing ```handleChange(fieldType)```on onChange instead of passing ```handleChange('input')``` to the FieldInput component in the first place? I don't get how this solved the issue. Aren't they the same?

Comment: As I said  in file ```FieldInput.tsx, line 41```, ```onChangeText={()=>handleChange(fieldType)}``` you didn't pass ```value``` of ```TextInput``` to ```handleChange``` function 

Check the 1 example here please https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput